# Let $f\in L^p$ and $g\in L^q$, then $f=0$ iff $\int fg=0$ for all $g$

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

The forward direction is easy. The backwards direction, it am not sure if they want me to show $f$ is identically $0$ or $0$ a.e. I assume almost everywhere as when we are talking about functions in $L^p$ we say $f=g$ if $f=g$ a.e. If it.s a.e the proof is very simple, if this is correct:

My proof: If $f \in L^p$ then $|f|^{p-1} \in L^q$ as $p$ and $q $ are conjugates. By Holders $\int |f|^p=0$ and so $f=0$ a.e.

Comment: It is indeed a.e. because elements of $L^p$ are equivalence classes of functions, so you are looking for a function in the same equivalence class as $0$.

Comment: With $\ast$ you mean the convolution or multiplication?

Comment: @MariosGretsas multiplication, sorry

Comment: A question: In which range of values are you getting p? Are you assuming $1 < p < \infty$?

Comment: @ABP $1 \leq p < \infty$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to prove this is by using Riesz theorem: If $1 \leq p < \infty$ you have a version of the Riesz representation Theorem for $L^{p}$ spaces. Let $T \in (L^{q})^{*}$ (dual of $L^{q}$) then there exists a unique $f \in L^{p}$, $\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} = 1$, such that 
\begin{equation}
T(g) = \int_{X}{fg}dx
\end{equation}
for every $g \in L^{q}$, moreover, $\|f\|_{L^{p}} = \|T\|_{(L^{q})^{*}}$. From this you conclude by observing that if $T \equiv 0$ then $f = 0$.

Now, the problem with your attempt is, as you are getting $g = |f|^{p-1}$ you'd have $\int{f|f|^{p-1}}dx = 0$ and not $\int{|f|^{p}} = 0$, even if you try $f^{p-1}$, $\int{f^{p}} = 0$ doesn't imply $f = 0$ ($f$ isn't necessarily non-negative), it'd be a better choice $g = f|f|^{p-2}$ and you can conclude as you did.

Comment: How about the function $Sgn(f)|f|^{p-1}$ ? it is in $L^q$ and gives us $\int |f|^p$. Also how do we know $|f|^{p-2} \in L^q$? Thank you for the use of Riesz, it is a cool application.

Comment: I didn't use that $|f|^{p-2} \in L^{q}$, I used that $g = f|f|^{p-2} \in L^{q}$, in this case: $|g| = |f|^{p-1}$. $Sgn(f)|f|^{p-1}$ would also work.

Comment: I see! Thank you @ABP